# New Z3 .NET API for fixed point

Tags: .net, z3

Since Z3 has released new .NET API, it seems to me that the API for fixed point has changed.

However I cannot find detail about how to use the new API.

Does anyone could offer me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the interest. I am trying to get a more decent tutorial together for the fixed point facilities. It will be available by next week. The distribution comes with a sample on using the fixed point facilities from the legacy C API.

Best Regards,
Nikolaj